# Office365, Admin.Microsoft, Is there a way to receive all missing mailbox emails from my exchange server?

Tags: email, email-accounts

We are trying not to miss any emails sent to our company, as some of our business contacts are contacted using employee's emails for example: **Sara@OurCompany.com** is contacting with **partner@partnerCompany.com**

But Sara has resigned, so we closed her mailbox, how can we not loose any emails coming to any mailbox? Currently when an employee resigned will setup mail forward for every person.

What we are trying to achieve if someone tries to email this email **someRandomEmail@OurCompany.com** this email will be forwarded to **missing@OurCompany.com**

I couldn't find a global solution to not miss any email coming to us

I hope I'm in the right community, if not please help me find the right one, Thank you.

Comment: What you are after is a wild card forwarder.  I can't answer if Office has this or not.  But I can tell you that you will likely regret using it.  You will get spammed to death...trust me on this...I found out the hard way.